# Using Hibernate to pull records based on the number of records in another table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a Users table that holds two different kinds of users (A and B). Type A users can have relationships with type B users (which is recorded in a Relationships table). The number of relationships that a Type A User can have with type B users is recorded in a field in another table.

I want to have Hibernate return all type A users that do not have all of their relationships established. I have a SQL query that will do it. What do I need to do?

***EDIT***

I've managed to get this working by throwing my query into a session.createSQLQuery(), but it seems weird to have a block of SQL in the midst of all of this to-the-point, awesome hibernate code. I would, I think, rather have it in HSQL or Hibernate objects, if possible.

This is the pseudo-query that I'm trying to convert to HSQL:

```
select userId 
from (
  select user_id, max_mentees, count(connection_id) num_mentees 
  from user_table 
  join mentor on mentor_id = user_id and user_status = 'ACTIVE'
  left join connections on connection_mentor_id = mentor_id 
    and connection_status = 'ACTIVE' and connection_end > sysdate 
  group by user_id, max_mentees, connection_id
)
where (max_mentees > num_mentees) 
group by user_id
```

Comment: `I want to have Hibernate return all type A users that do not have all of their relationships established` When? When doing what?

Comment: Basically, A users will be mentors of B users and an A user has a limit of how many "mentees" they can have at a time. The count is to see how many B (mentee) users are assigned to the A (mentor) user so that we can compare it to the limit number in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-load

I know you can do this in a mapping file; not sure how it works with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Mentor class that has a one to many relationship with a MentorRelationship class, you would do something like this:

```
session.createQuery("from Mentor mentor where mentor.menteeRelationships.size < mentor.menteeRelationships.maxNumberOfRelationships")
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have Hibernate return all type A users that do not have all of their relationships established. I have a SQL query that will do it. What do I need to do?

Honestly, your question is still very unclear (at least for me) and without seeing the SQL, without seeing your object model and the mappings, it seems hard to be precise and my suggestion would be to either:

- convert the SQL into HQL ~or~
- run your query as a [Native Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

If you expect a more detailed answer, you should IMO provide more details.

Comment: I've updated my question with the query I'm trying to reproduce.